# Remove string from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that contain number and string, I want to remove all string from the array.
Here is the array:

```
var numbOnly = [1, 3, "a", 7];
```

In this case, I want to remove `a` from `numbOnly` (**result** `numbOnly = [1, 3, 7]`).

Thanks.

Comment: iterate the array and check it dataType using `typeof`

Comment: I take it you meant `"a"`, not `a`? Or is `a` a variable containing a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use this:

```
var numbOnly = [1, 3, "a", 7];
var newArr = numbOnly.filter(isFinite)  // [1, 3, 7]
```

The above works really well if you don't have strings like `"1"` in the array. To overcome that, you can filter the array like this:

```
newArr = numbOnly.filter(function(x){
   return typeof x == "number"; 
});
```

Comment: I'd to do `.filter(isFinite)`. `Number` will filter out zeros.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function along with [`Object.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) like this

```
var array = [1, 3, 'a', 7];

var numbOnly = array.filter(function(currentItem) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(currentItem).indexOf('Number')!==-1;
});

console.log(numbOnly);
# [ 1, 3, 7 ]
```

Alternatively, you can use [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) to check the type like this

```
return typeof currentItem === 'number';
```

The `filter` function will retain the current element in the resulting list only if the function passed to it returns `true` for the current item. In this case, we are checking if the type of the current item is number or not. So, `filter` will keep only the items whose type is number, in the result.